# PHP exec() not working

Tags: php, exec, executable

I need to execute this below code

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\acm\upload\P0005\A0020>pdflatex.exe demo
```

in php. I used the below coding

```
shell_exec("cmd pdflatex.exe upload/P0005/A0020/ demo");
```

But its not working ..  How can i execute in php?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? Do you know what a command is? Where is the binary placed? Why don't you use the exact same command? What's the reason of writing it differently if you want to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the full paths :

```
shell_exec("cmd E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\acm\\upload\\P0005\\A0020\\pdflatex.exe E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\acm\\upload\\P0005\\A0020\\ demo");
```

or

```
shell_exec("cmd E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\acm\\upload\\P0005\\A0020\\pdflatex.exe demo");
```

the second example matches the first command in your question - the double backslash (`\\`) is used to print a `\` character - the first is `\` is to escape the second

Comment: i tried that one.. but its not working..  please check this image http://daytimeprofits.com/images/cmd.jpg . i need to execute the same in exec or shell_exec command in php

Comment: @DipenBaskaran which one did you try ? i suggest the second is probably the more correct one

Comment: Second one i tried. When i execute the same one in command prompt its working. but in php its not working . Please check this one http://daytimeprofits.com/images/cmd.jpg

Comment: @DipenBaskaran try removing the `cmd`

Comment: Are you running in [safe mode](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php) ?